# Iteration over class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `abalone` with three attributes `M`, `I` and `F`. Accessing them like so:

```
abalone.M
Out[81]:
array([[ 0.455 ,  0.365 ,  0.095 , ...,  0.2245,  0.101 ,  0.15  ],
       [ 0.35  ,  0.265 ,  0.09  , ...,  0.0995,  0.0485,  0.07  ],
       [ 0.44  ,  0.365 ,  0.125 , ...,  0.2155,  0.114 ,  0.155 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.59  ,  0.44  ,  0.135 , ...,  0.439 ,  0.2145,  0.2605],
       [ 0.6   ,  0.475 ,  0.205 , ...,  0.5255,  0.2875,  0.308 ],
       [ 0.71  ,  0.555 ,  0.195 , ...,  0.9455,  0.3765,  0.495 ]])
```

works splendidly. How would I go about iterating over them? My try

```
for item in [M, I, F]:
    abalone.item
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-c9c2187c3451> in <module>()
----> 1 for item in [M, I, F]:
      2     abalone.item

NameError: name 'M' is not defined
```

doesn't work unfortunately.

Edit: Trying

```
for item in ['M', 'I', 'F']:
    abalone.item
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-b9d61335686f> in <module>()
      1 for item in ['M', 'I', 'F']:
----> 2     abalone.item

AttributeError: 'Abalone' object has no attribute 'item'
```

does not work either.

Comment: The type of abalone.M is `array.array` or `list` ? Sorry it confuses me.

Comment: It is a numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
for attr, value in abalone.__dict__.items():
    print attr,value
```

If it doesn't work then let me know.

Edited (according to change in problem):

```
l = ['M','I','F']
for attr, value in x.__dict__.iteritems():
    if attr in l:
        print attr,value
```

Here l will contain the subset of attributes you want to access.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected my question and tried out your suggestion as well which doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: that's okay. I edited my answer try this method. Tested this myself so it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that works but unfortunately it doesn't help in my case because I am only iterating through a subset. So I specifically need to get my code above working..

Comment: you should have mentioned that. anyway I Edited my code accordinly. Try that know.